# Generic Comparator

Tags: java, generics, collections, reflection

I have tried to make a generic comparator with the use of reflection, but I am not sure how efficient it is or if it is the right way to do so  Also, I don't know how it will handle **dates**.

```
<T> List<?> sortList(List<T> l,String field,Class<T> c) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IntrospectionException{  

   final Field f = c.getDeclaredField(field);
   PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = new 
   PropertyDescriptor(f.getName(),c);
   final Method getter = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();

       Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<T>() {
            public int compare(T e1, T e2) {
                int i=0;
                try {
                    if(f.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)){
                        i = getter.invoke(e1).toString().compareTo(getter.invoke(e2).toString());
                    }    
                    else if(f.getType().isAssignableFrom(int.class)){
                      i = Integer.parseInt(getter.invoke(e1).toString()) - 
                        Integer.parseInt(getter.invoke(e2).toString()); 
                    } 
                    else if(f.getType().isAssignableFrom(long.class)){
                      i = (int)(Long.parseLong(getter.invoke(e1).toString()) - 
                        Long.parseLong(getter.invoke(e2).toString()));  
                    }
                    else if(f.getType().isAssignableFrom(float.class)){
                         if(Float.parseFloat(getter.invoke(e1).toString()) - 
                                 Float.parseFloat(getter.invoke(e2).toString()) < 0)
                             i = -1;
                         else if(Float.parseFloat(getter.invoke(e1).toString()) - 
                                 Float.parseFloat(getter.invoke(e2).toString()) > 0)
                             i = 1;
                         else 
                             i = 0;
                    }   
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return i;
            }
        });
   return l;
}
```

Comment: A generic comparator does not make any sense since usually there is no generic way to compare your custom objects. E.g.: what about the order in which the properties of your objects are used for compare?

Comment: i thought this can be used in UI by adding a sort button only for ascending or descending order

Comment: Your generic Comparator does not even know how many properties there are in your object. how can it respect any externally created order? The only useful generic approach I see is to by using a `@SortKey(order=n)` annotation on properties. IMHO anything else will be too complex to be usefull...

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It looks horrible right now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to pass the sorting key as a String into your method, thus needing reflection.

But let's have a look at the implementation.

It's overly complicated and buggy.

However you implement your method, you can only sort by a field if that field has a type that allows comparing its values, e.g. an `int`, a `String` and so on. For e.g. a `java.awt.Point` field, I wouldn't know a universal way how to sort by that. And all the types that you might sort by typically implement `Comparable` [A special case are the primitive types like `int` or `double`, where their wrapper counterpart `Integer` or `Double` implements `Comparable`]. And `Comparable` gives you the comparison function for free that you wrote in a very complicated way.

Here's an improved version of your method:

```
public static <T> List<?> sortList(List<T> l, String field, Class<T> c) 
    throws ReflectiveOperationException, IntrospectionException {  

    final Field f = c.getDeclaredField(field);

    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(f.getName(),c);
    final Method getter = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
    Class<?> returnType = getter.getReturnType();

    if (Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType) || returnType.isPrimitive()) {
        // The result from invoke() will be Comparable
        Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<T>() {
            public int compare(T e1, T e2) {
                try {
                    Comparable val1 = (Comparable) getter.invoke(e1);
                    Comparable val2 = (Comparable) getter.invoke(e2);
                    return val1.compareTo(val2);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    throw e;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot compare on field " + field + " of type " + returnType.getName());
    }
    return l;
}
```

Finally some comments regarding your implementation:

```
i = Integer.parseInt(getter.invoke(e1).toString()) - 
       Integer.parseInt(getter.invoke(e2).toString());
```

This is effectively `i = (Integer) getter.invoke(e1) - (Integer) getter.invoke(e2);`. And the risk is overflow: if the value from e1 is 2000000000, and the value from e2 is -2000000000 (both fit within the integer number range), you'd expect e1 greater than e2, resulting in positive comparison value. But subtracting the two numbers gives a negative result (as 4000000000 is outside of the int range und thus overflows to a negative value). So you'd better use `Integer.compare()` instead of subtracting.

Even worse with the `Long` case: casting the subtraction result to `int` cuts off the higher binary digits, so giving you wrong results even in cases where the subtraction still was well within the long number range. Use `Long.compare()` instead.

You do things like `Integer.parseInt(getter.invoke(e1).toString())`, which is complete nonsense. `getter.invoke(e1)` already gives you an Integer, but you convert that to the decimal String representation of that number, just to parse it back to the original number. That's a huge waste of CPU resources. You just have to tell the compiler that the result is an Integer: `(Integer) getter.invoke(e1)`.

Your choice of using `PropertyDescriptor` forces the user of your method to have both a getter and a setter method for the field that you use for sorting, although you really only need the getter.